# Map to pivot table with 3 criteria

Tags: excel, excel-formula, pivot-table

[image]

How to map the amount from pivot table?

I have a very long list of rows in my standard table and I’m trying to map  three criteria: column country, function and cost from the pivot table so that I can find the correct amount.

Comment: Hello and welcome to StackOverflow. Please take some time to read the help page, especially the sections named ["What topics can I ask about here?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and ["What types of questions should I avoid asking?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask). And more importantly, please read [the Stack Overflow question checklist](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/156810/204922). You might also want to learn about [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Examples](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).
After that please edit your question.

Comment: Use `XLOOKUP()` function.